# why is the on relaese failing on this code in the bottomnavigation yet i want the icon there when pressed it goesback to the home screen

Tags: python, kivymd

:
canvas.before:
Rectangle:
size: self.size
pos: self.pos
source: 'mainlib.jpg'  # Change this to your image file

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': .1}
    size_hint_y: .8
    size_hint_x: 0.8

    MDCard:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        width: dp(200)
        height: dp(50)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .97}

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint_y: 0
            size_hint_x: .9
            width: dp(20)

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
                on_release: app.open_menu()

    MDCard:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_x: .6
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(50)
        width: dp(280)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .45, 'center_y': .9}

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Offices'
            halign: 'center'
            font_style: 'Body1'

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .84
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            spacing: 25
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: [25, 0]

            MDCard:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                width: dp(120)
                height: dp(120)
                padding: 15
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

                Button:  # Using a Button instead of Image
                    on_release: root.switch_to_home_screen()  # Update this function
                    Image:
                        source: 'library.png'
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 80, 64
                        width: dp(100)
                        height: dp(100)
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

                Label:
                    text: 'Library'
                    halign: 'center'

            MDCard:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                padding: 15
                width: dp(120)
                height: dp(120)

                Button:  # Using a Button instead of Image
                    on_release: root.show_faculties()  # Update this function
                    Image:
                        source: 'health center.png'
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 64, 64
                        width: dp(100)
                        height: dp(100)
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

                Label:
                    text: 'Health Center'
                    halign: 'center'

            # Add more MDCards for other offices

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 0
        size_hint_x: .94
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.03}

        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen1'
                text: 'HOME'
                icon: 'home'
                on_release: app.root.ids.your_screen_manager_id.current = 'HomeScreen'
```

after having this ::

```
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        source: 'homemain.jpg'  # Replace 'background_image.png' with your image file
ScreenManager:  # Add a ScreenManager here and assign an ID
    id: your_screen_manager_id

    Screen:  
        name: 'HomeScreen'  

MDCard:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    width: dp(200)
    height: dp(50)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y':.97}

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: 0
        size_hint_x: .9
        width: dp(20)

        # Your menu bar with icons
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'menu'
            on_release: app.open_menu()  # Replace with the f

MDCard:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_x: .6
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(50)
    width: dp(280)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .45, 'center_y': .8}

        
    MDTextField:
        hint_text: 'Search'
        size_hint_x: None
        
        width: dp(800)
        icon_right: 'magnify'
        hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1  # White hint text color

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: .55
    size_hint_x: .8
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.75,'center_y': 0.3}

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3  # Number of columns in the grid
        spacing: 25  # Spacing between images
        

        # Add your cards with icons here
        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 90, 90
            padding: 15

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'offices.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                on_press:root.manager.current = 'offices'

            Label:
                text: 'Offices'
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 90, 90
            padding: 15

            MDIconButton:
                id: academic_icon
                icon: 'school'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                on_release: app.show_faculties()

            Label:
                text: 'Academic'
                halign: 'center'
        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 90, 90
            padding: 15

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'medical-bag'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

            Label:
                text: 'Health'
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 90, 90
            padding: 15

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'announce.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

            Label:
                text: 'Announce'
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 90, 90
            padding: 15

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'admin.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                on_press:root.manager.current = 'admin'

            Label:
                text: 'Admin'
                halign: 'center'
        
        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 90, 90
            padding: 15

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'location.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

            Label:
                text: 'Location'
                halign: 'center'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: 0
    size_hint_x: .9
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.03}

    MDBottomNavigation:
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 1'
            text: 'PROFILE'
            icon: 'account'

            # Your content for Tab 1 goes here

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 2'
            text: 'HOME'
            icon: 'home'

            # Your content for Tab 2 goes here

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 3'
            text: 'SETTINGS'
            icon: 'dots-vertical'

            # Your content for Tab 3 goes here

    Widget:  # This widget will take the remaining space at the bottom
```

## Define your App class and any necessary functions here

:
canvas.before:
Color:
rgba: 0, 0, 0.08, 1  # Dark blue color (R, G, B, A)
Rectangle:
size: self.size
pos: self.pos

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(90)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .9}

 

    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}
        on_release: app.open_menu()  # Replace with the function to open your menu

        
    MDTextField:
        hint_text: 'Search'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: dp(500)
        icon_right: 'magnify'
        hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1  # White hint text color

MDLabel:
    text: 'Administration Services'
    font_style: 'H4'
    halign: 'center'
    pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.8}
    size_hint_y: .9
    height: dp(30)
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: dp(50)
    height:dp(300)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.35, 'center_y': 0.5}


    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        spacing: 10
        size_hint_x: .2
        size_hint_y: .3
        width: dp(200)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        MDCard:
            
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 150
            width: dp(500)
            height: dp(60)
            padding: 15
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.5}

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'admission.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.5}

            Label:
                text: 'Admission Forms'
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 150
            size_hint_x: None
            width: dp(500)
            height: dp(60)
            padding: 15
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.5}

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'tution.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.5}

            Label:
                text: 'Tuition'
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 150
            width: dp(500)
            height: dp(60)
            padding: 15
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.5}

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'welfree.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

            Label:
                text: 'Students Welfare'
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 100
            width: dp(500)
            height: dp(60)
            padding: 15
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.5}

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'sports.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 64, 64
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

            Label:
                text: 'Sports'
                halign: 'center'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: 0
    size_hint_x: .9
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.03}

    MDBottomNavigation:
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 1'
            text: 'PROFILE'
            icon: 'account'

            # Your content for Tab 1 goes here

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 2'
            text: 'HOME'
            icon: 'home'

            # Your content for Tab 2 goes here

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 3'
            text: 'SETTINGS'
            icon: 'school'

                # Your content for Tab 3 goes here
```

tried using an ai bot ti identify the error but failed

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)